# How can I save a file on remote server with js and php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I use [html2canvas.js](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) to save images. 
I knwo how to use this if is in the same location/server with the php files.

But now I want to use the script in eBay listing template and save the image to my server.
Is this possible?

This is my php file:

```
<?php
function ImageFillAlpha($image, $color) {
    imagefilledrectangle($image, 0, 0, imagesx($image), imagesy($image), $color);
}
function imageCreateCorners($sourceImageFile, $name, $radius) {
    # test source image
    if (file_exists($sourceImageFile)) {
        $res = is_array($info = getimagesize($sourceImageFile));
    }
    else
        $res = false;
    # open image
    if ($res) {
        $w = $info[0];
        $h = $info[1];
        switch ($info['mime']) {
            case 'image/jpeg': $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($sourceImageFile);
                break;
            case 'image/gif': $src = imagecreatefromgif($sourceImageFile);
                break;
            case 'image/png': $src = imagecreatefrompng($sourceImageFile);
                break;
            default:
                $res = false;
        }
    }
    # create corners
    if ($res) {
        $q = 10; #change this if you want
        $radius *= $q;
        $r = 0;
        $g = 0;
        $b = 0;
        $nw = $w * $q;
        $nh = $h * $q;
        $img = imagecreatetruecolor($nw, $nh);
        $alphacolor = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);
        imagealphablending($img, false);
        imagesavealpha($img, true);
        imagefilledrectangle($img, 0, 0, $nw, $nh, $alphacolor);
        imagefill($img, 0, 0, $alphacolor);
        imagecopyresampled($img, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nw, $nh, $w, $h);
        # resize image down
        $dest = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
        imagealphablending($dest, false);
        imagesavealpha($dest, true);
        imagefilledrectangle($dest, 0, 0, $w, $h, $alphacolor);
        imagecopyresampled($dest, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $nw, $nh);
        # output image
        $res = $dest;
        imagedestroy($src);
        imagedestroy($img);
        imagepng($res, 'cart/'.$name);
    }
    return $res;
}
$image = $_POST['plate_image'];
$ebay_user = $_POST['ebay_user'];
$decoded = base64_decode(str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $image));
$date = date('m-d-Y', time());
$name = "evgrave-".$ebay_user."-".$date.".png";
file_put_contents("/var/www/html/SERVERLOCATION/img/" . $name, $decoded);
$full_path = "/var/www/html/SERVERLOCATION/img/" . $name;
imageCreateCorners($full_path, $name, 25);
$name1 = 'img/'.$name;
echo '<div class="download">';
echo '<br /><p>Result:</p><br />';
echo "<img src='$name1' alt='image' id='img' />";
echo '<p class="download-btn"><a id="download" class="left" href="download.php?&img=' . $name1 .'">Download Image</a><a id="send" class="right" href="#">Send Order</a></p>';
echo '</div>';
?>
```

and this is the js function:

```
                html2canvas($('#output'), {
                    "logging": true,
                    "onrendered": function(canvas){
                        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                        $.post('REMOTESERVER/image.php',{
                            plate_image: dataURL,
                            ebay_user: ebay_user
                        },function(data){
                            $('.overlay').remove();
                            $('#result').html(data);
                        });  
                    }
                });
```

any help?
thanks

Comment: Possibly use ssh2_scp_send to send the file from your local server to a remote one. http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-scp-send.php (or use FTP)

Comment: there's no file, when i click submit the javascript is generating a image (prind screen of a div id) and use the php for that and for saving too. The problem is that i use the js in ebay and i have the php on my server, where i want to save the img too (bec ebay doesn't support php)

Comment: But you are saving the image (the print screen) on your server in a file, right? If that is the case, we can use `header(...)` to render it an image within the browser.

Comment: yes, I want to save it (.png image) from eBay to my server and I don't really know how :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it multiple ways. Here's two of them (although they have the same concept.)

#### Method 1 - SCP

- Upload the file to your local server
- Create a script that runs in the background, and [ssh2_scp_send()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-scp-send.php) the local file to your remote server via cron/straight after file write.

  - [SCP PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-scp-send.php)

#### Method 2 - FTP

*This is very similar to method 1, but uses a different protocol; FTP*

- Upload the file to your local server
- Create a script that connects to your remote server via FTP, and uploads/copies the local file to your remote server via cron/straight after file write.

  - [FTP PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/ftp)

Comment: Links are in my reply. See the last bullet point of each method.